# Area enclosed by a curve defined by parametric equations

Tags: surface-integrals

> A point set $B$ in the $(x,y)-$plane is determined by its parametric equation:
>
> $$r(u,v)=(u,10u^2+v\cdot u\cdot (5-10u)), 0\leq u\leq \frac{1}{2}, 0\leq v \leq 1$$
>
> Determine the area of the point set $B$.

---

I'm not completely sure how to do this. Do I just determine the Jacobi function and then find the determinant of that function?

Comment: see for example (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889524).

Comment: I have changed "the area of a given point" (a point has no area since Euclides:) into something more meaningful.